# SIFT: Do I need to compute the orientation in absense of rotations

Tags: image-processing, sift

I am trying to understand SIFT and I have a question about the computation of orientation for each keypoints. Suppose I am using SIFT to compute transformations between images where I know that the images are only translated with respect to each other. Can I get away without computing the orientation and only compute the descriptor for an angle of 0 degrees?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is the way to go with what you want to do. I think maybe a better way to go about it would be to extract SIFT from both images, and perform RANSAC to get the homography and from there you should have the angle of rotation. If you find a way to do this though please post :)

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use RANSAC to find the homography but I was wondering if the SIFT descriptor can be computed without computing the orientations in this case. If I am not interested in the rotation component of the homography, can I somehow skip the orientation computation during SIFT?

Comment: You know typically the descriptor is computed for each orientation of the keypoint. So, can I compute just one descriptor for each keypoint with the orientation angle set to 0? Would it affect the quality of the estimated transformation?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so- the orientation assignment works a bit like HOG in that you're calculating the differences in the pixel values around your keypoint- then you do voting to get the orientation assignment, you do this for all the points around do that you get the invariance part as opposed to hog which is obviously oriented. Thus I think setting this value to zero would be meaningless. However, I haven't tried so its possible I'm wrong. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: Yes, you can. It is called "upright" SIFT and gives a better results than oriented, for example, photos of buildings. Of course, not rotated photos.